# Error: initializer element is not constant - linux driver

Tags: c, module, struct, kernel, constants

I am really not able to solve this issue.

> error: initializer element is not constant
>
> error: (near initialization for tca6507_leds1.leds.num_leds)

I think the problem is related to `struct led_info *leds` inside `led_platform_data`. Is this somehow not a const since it is a pointer? I am particularly baffled since `led_platform_data` and `led_info` are part of the linux kernel. `tca6507_platform_data` is also a part of a driver that is included in the kernel source.

Here is my initialization:

```
static struct led_info tca6507_led_infos[] = {
    {
            .name                   = "left_blue",
            .default_trigger        = "heartbeat",
    },
};

static struct led_platform_data tca6507_leds2 = {
    .leds           = tca6507_led_infos,
};

struct tca6507_platform_data tca6507_leds1 = {
    .leds           = tca6507_leds1
};
```

All the structs are defined in header files that I did not write.

```
struct led_info {
    const char      *name;
    const char      *default_trigger;
    int             flags;
};

struct led_platform_data {
    int             num_leds;
    struct          led_info *leds;
};

struct tca6507_platform_data {
    struct led_platform_data leds;
#ifdef CONFIG_GPIOLIB
    int gpio_base;
    void (*setup)(unsigned gpio_base, unsigned ngpio);
#endif
};
```

Comment: You're trying to initialize a data member of `tca6507_leds1` with... `tca6507_leds1`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is right in the middle of this three line bit:

```
struct tca6507_platform_data tca6507_leds1 = {
    .leds           = tca6507_leds1
};
```

What is the (compile time) value of `tca6507_leds1`?  Note that it is a structure, not an array.

Compare that with the (valid):

```
static struct led_platform_data tca6507_leds2 = {
    .leds           = tca6507_led_infos,
};
```

What is the (compile time) value of `tca6507_led_infos`?  (Note that it *is* an array, and the "value" of an array is the address of its first element.)  And most importantly (perhaps I should not have buried the lede :-) ), compare with the (also valid):

```
static struct led_info tca6507_led_infos[] = {
    {
            .name                   = "left_blue",
            .default_trigger        = "heartbeat",
    },
};
```

Note that instead of using the value of a variable, the initializer here is a brace-enclosed list of items.  This (like the failing case) is an instance of `struct led_info`, which must contain one actual `struct led_platform_data` instance (not a pointer to one-or-more, as is used in `struct led_platform_data`).

---

(The above is meant as an exercise.  The answer is, the value of a structure is the value of the structure—but that is not a compile-time constant.  Moreover, you are trying to use the value of the structure that you have not yet finished initializing in the first place.  You need X to set X but you have to find X first, which you do by finding X, and there's no end to the recursion.)